# Class constructor BaseService cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use angular js service as ES6 class. But getting error.

Class constructor BaseService cannot be invoked without 'new'.

Here is the code of service.

```
"use babel";

(function() {
  'use strict';

  class BaseService {
    constructor() {
      this.data = {
        items: []
      };
    }

    loadData() {
      this.data.items = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
    }
  }

  angular.module('app').service('BaseService',  BaseService);
}());
```

Here is a link which I am trying.
https://embed.plnkr.co/D9MEJZe4pF6oztf7DP31/

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: My question is that why my above code gives error 
Class constructor BaseService cannot be invoked without 'new'
I am including the base service from index .html. 
Please see https://embed.plnkr.co/D9MEJZe4pF6oztf7DP31/ for full code which is not working.
Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// your Base Service class file
export default class BaseService {
    constructor() {
        this.data = {
            items: []
        };
    }
}

// your Angular service file
import BaseService from './base.service.js'; // relative path to BaseService file

export default class MyService extends BaseService {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

// module definition file
import MyService from './my.service.js'; // relative path to MyService file
module.exports = angular.module('myMod',[])
.service('MyService', MyService);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.
This code gives error  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import.
I am new to ES6. I want my services to act as class so I can perform inheritance.

Comment: This code absolutely works (I use this pattern every day, all day), but you will still need to compile it with Babel first.

Comment: Unless your "Base" service is, by itself, also a true Angular service, you wouldn't need to register it as an Angular service. It can be a standalone "class" that you extend in your registered Angular service. I'll update my code example to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in the AngularJS version (1.5.0-rc.0) you are using. It fails to correctly construct a class. Upgrade to version 1.5.0 or higher and the error will disappear.